# If I open a document from a USB flash drive but do not save it to the computer,how can i access the file’s contents after I remove the drive?

Tags: hard-drive, usb

If I open a document from a USB flash drive but do not save it to the computer, how can i access the file’s contents after I remove the drive?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. The easy answer is; you can't. But this question is lacking details needed for anyone to competently help you. Please add details of what you have tried so far and exactly what you are trying to accomplish. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: You can't.  The temporary file is stored on the removal drive.  This means all copies of the document reside on an external disk and in system memory.  Once the document is closed the system no longer has access to any of the temporary files

Answer (score 3):

You don't... You removed the drive that contains the file and didn't save a local copy on another medium, such as an internal hard drive, there is nothing on your computer to access, so you can't open the file again.

To open the document again, reinsert the USB drive.

You could easily equate this to watching a movie on a disc... You insert the DVD into the player and press play, you watch the movie, then you remove the DVD disc from the player. Can you now press play and watch the movie without the disc in the player? No, you can't, you have to reinsert the disc to watch it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the usb drive you can't anymore get access to your files.

You can have the follow options:

- you can save you files on a online cloud service (you can access your files unless you don't have an internet connection)
- also you can save you files on a local NAS (Network Attached Storage)
- if you would like to have a temporary copy on a virtual drive, which store your files unless you turn off you computer (RamDisk)
- you can also use a virtual machine to store those files (more technical experience is required)

Comment: Please don't sign your posts. This site does it automatically.

Comment: I'm sorry I will not sign my posts anymore

Answer (score -1):

This is similar to deleting a file that you still have open.

Run:

```
lsof |grep filename
```

e.g. I had file called test with data in it, was editing it but then removed it from filesystem whilst still editing (I removed file test and `.test.swp`):

```
lsof |grep test
vim       19408                  sah    4u      REG                8,3     12288   3658163 /home/sah/.test.swp
```

from this we have the pid(19408) and the filedescriptor 4:

```
ls -l /proc/19408/fd/4 
lrwx------ 1 sah sah 64 Apr  8 15:57 /proc/19408/fd/4 -> /home/sah/.test.swp
```

Then just:

```
cp /proc/19408/fd/4  /home/sah/.test.swp
vi -r test
```

and its back..